# ASP.NET MVC 4 ViewModel - XSS Vunerabilities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and have a question regarding Cross-site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities with the underlying ViewModel.

I am aware that ASP.NET does provide some request validation, but is there anything else I need to do to prevent XSS attacks? Do I need to use AntiXSS to sanitise each property of the ViewModel once it's been posted back to the server?

I did try entering alert("Hello"); into one of my textbox inputs and ASP.NET correctly caught it as potentially dangerous, but I just want to make sure I haven't missed something else.

Thanks for any and all advice.

Comment: This question makes an odd assumption, which is that XSS has something to do with the properties of the ViewModel. XSS occurs because of a flaw in the way that data is rendered to a browser (usually, the fact that it is not HTMLencoded). So it's a View level thing. It is possible to knock out XSS by restricting the properties of the ViewModel, but I think that it's the wrong place to do it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance in these things, I'm relatively new to web development so still very much learning. What I meant was that if I had a form which populated various properties of the ViewModel to then be stored in a database. I thought that I might need to 'sanitise' the data entered to avoid anything untoward being stored (as the data will inevitably be displayed in another page at some point). I thought perhaps I might need to check each of the ViewModel properties before storage, rather than store blindly and sanitise at a later stage when the data is displayed in a page.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. My opinion is that it's the wrong approach (others may disagree). For one it makes you less diligent about knocking out XSS points in the View - there may be other ways in which these could be exploited, if data can be changed without doing a roundtrip to the DB, or if there is ever another route to entering data into the DB. But mainly, the thought of addressing a presentation layer issue at the business logic layer just gives me the vapours.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, I was thinking of it more as a 'belt and braces' approach to make sure any data entered would be checked/sanitised to avoid bad data going into the database, and likewise sanitise anything being presented in the view as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Razor will santize every thing except what's ever is in `@Html.Raw()`.

Read this [article](http://www.everythinggeek.co.uk/asp-net/asp-net-mvc-security-preventing-cross-site-scripting/) to gain more insights about how to prevent  Cross-Site Request Forgery

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that might be the case but I wasn't sure.

Comment: The link redirects to an invalid URL. This is the correct URL http://www.adamriddick.com/2013/04/asp-net-mvc-security-preventing-cross-site-scripting/